# How to prove that the Laplacian for a directed graph has an eigenvalue at 0?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

If Laplacian L = D-A where D is the degree matrix and A is an 0-1 adjacency matrix for a directed graph. How can we prove that this Laplacian has an eigenvalue at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\textbf{1}$ be the function taking the value $1$ at each vertex. Then by explicit calculation, we see that both $D\textbf{1}$ and $A\textbf{1}$ are equal to the function taking the value $\deg(v)$ at each vertex $v$. Consequently,
$$
(D-A)\textbf{1}=0,
$$
which means that $\textbf{1}$ is an eigenvector of the Laplacian with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the help of Gershgorin Disk Theorem and Perron Frobenius Theorem?

Comment: @m1cro1ce none of those results are necessary just to prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian. I have given a complete and self-contained proof here that does not rely on any external result. If you do not understand, please clarify what it is you do not understand.

Comment: One doubt would be how is $A\textbf{1} = deg(v)$? Because $A\textbf{1}$ will give us only the in-degree for every node in the network while $deg(v)$ is the sum of both in-degree and out-degree at a node in a directed graph right?

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect. I didn't clarify in or out degree since you didn't either in your definition of $D$. But it is not the sum, it must be one or the other (whichever matches the convention used for the adjacency matrix: if $A_{ij}$ is directed edge from $i$ to $j$, or from $j$ to $i$.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Laplacian_matrix_for_simple_graphs

Comment: Okay, then it leads to correct result as u said in the answer. Just a follow-up though. Is there a possibility that we can get eigenvalue 0 with some eigenvector other than $\textbf{1}$. I mean in this case is the eigenvalue 0 algebraically simple?